# How to get href text which contains .xls or .xlsx text in an anchor tag using regex

Tags: c#, regex

Using regex I want to fetch an href which contains .xls or .xlsx text

I want to stick to this regex

```
<a\s*[^>]*\s*href\s*=\s*((?:[^ ]|[\n\r])+)\s*[^>]*>.*?<\/a>
```

But what should I add here so that I can get only the link which contains .xls or .xlsx text in anchore tag.

Comment: [Do Not Use Regex For Parsing html/xml and the like!](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/1336590) - For html use [Html Agility Pack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/), for xml use [XDocument](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.xml.linq.xdocument.aspx)/[XElement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.xml.linq.xelement.aspx)

Comment: @Corak sorry but I have to stick to this regex.

Answer (score 0):

Many potential problems doing it this way, but using JavaScript:

```
var re = new RegExp(/<a\s*[^>]*\s*href\s*=\s*((?:[^ ]|[\n\r])+)((\.xls)|(\.xlsx))\s*[^>]*>.*?<\/a>/ig);
txt = 'ok, here you go: <a href="test.xls">test file</a> and <a href="http://not.test.com">not file</a>, but another <a href = "http://www.xls.com/test.xls">test file</a>!';
txt.match(re)
```

*`=>  ['<a href="test.xls">test file</a>', '<a href = "http://www.xls.com/test.xls">test file</a>']`*

Comment: any other suggestions

Comment: Corak's suggestions will work, or with JavaScript just traverse the DOM using `document.getElementsByTag ('a')` and use a simpler regex on each src attribute.